# Python OS error when changing dir to write new file, have to use chdir()

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

This looks quite easy/dumb, but after some googling and searching here and there, it seems that this may be so simple that no one has asked.
I am trying to open a txt file for writing, in python 3.4.2 (tried on 3.4.1 too), and an os error occurred.
Being new to programming, what I am trying to do is really simple and naive, I just want to have a new file for text output in another directory that is different from the "default" one (i.e. from my desktop to the c drive). Using chdir() is a requirement.

```
import os
os.chdir("C:\\")
outfile=open("asdf.txt","w")
```

The error is like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
outfile=open("asdf.txt","w")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'asdf.txt'
```

If I change the above code to this
    `os.chdir("c:")`
it has no change in the directory but no error.
 `os.chdir("c:/")` also brings up the error. All codes are tried on both pyshell and IDLE, the last line of OSError are the same.

Could anyone tell me what I have messed up with? 
This is my first ever question asked here too.
Thank you for your help and kindness!

Comment: I'm not sure. I see you're using pyshell which may be doing some path manipulation (just a guess). If all else fails, I suggest using full paths when opening a file as opposed to relative paths.

Comment: `outfile=open("c:\\asdf.txt",'w')` also results in
`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:`, with or without the chdir() thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to create a file in a directory that you do not have permissions to create a file in. Stop doing that.

Comment: Do not allow arbitrary processes to write to any directory they are not explicitly supposed to. Instead either use an appropriate existing directory or create a new directory for the script to write to.

Comment: To change the permission, I go to the cmd and type in `icacls c:\ /setintegritylevel M`, it does the job. However will this harm my computer or put my computer in risk?